# What was the largest battle axe used in battle?

Tags: weapons

What was the largest [battle axe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_axe) used in battle? By largest, I mean probably just heaviest.  I managed to find a post on quora about the heaviest weapon that didn't have a great answer.

Comment: So actually used in battle rather than just ceremonial?

Comment: Does a naval ram count as a large, ship-mounted, axe?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the Dane Axe, as seen here:

https://berloga-workshop.com/blog/342-dane-axe.html.

And possibly backed up here:

https://www.sciencealert.com/archaeologists-uncovered-one-of-the-biggest-viking-axes-ever.

Though the most likely answer is actually a *Pole*axe, like a Bardiche.

Comment: So the real question is when does a battle axe get so large that it ceases to be an axe and becomes a poleaxe?

Comment: A quick Google led me to: http://myarmoury.com/talk/viewtopic.5370.html so I'm ASSUMING that it basically means 'one is for chopping, one is an all-rounder'. It MIGHT be a question of the wooden shaft's length, or it might be the shape of the blade, I know bugger-all about this and just stumbled on this question by pure accident while researching for a Goshujin-sama to Yuku Isekai Survival fanfic.

Comment: Apparently, a big difference according to Wikipedia is that Poleaxes are meant to be top-heavy, but aren't used JUST for chopping. You can also go for stabbing, slashing, crushing, or using the base as a quarterstaff. Given that spears were made for taking down enemies at longer melee range, and (I BELIEVE) Halberds were intended to fight Knights by knocking them off their horses, Poleaxes would have been more for swinging than stabbing, and would rely on their weight to knock enemies down or break through plate armor, as opposed to swords and spears that don't have the weight to do so.

Comment: ...or it might just be the length of the shaft. That's usually what it comes down to, hur hur~.

Comment: Given that comments can get deleted, you might want to edit some of the above into your answer.

Comment: That picture in the first link is impressive, but quite misleading due to its perspecive.